# How to use `component` props twice

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my case i need compose AppBar and Container. But Container make AppBar to div tag, not header tag. How to do header tag ?

```
<AppBar color="primary" position="static" component={Container} maxWidth="xl">
```

Comment: You can nest them....

Comment: SakoBu 
nesting creates an extra div. I do not need it

Comment: instead of wrapping Container in a div tag, wrap it in header tag